# Need help getting a class name through an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class

I'm working on a tic-tac-toe game and I need some help. Here is how my board is set up:

---

```
[a1] [a2] [a3]  
[b1] [b2] [b3]  
[c1] [c2] [c3]
```

---

Those values are the classes that I've assigned those particular spaces. In jQuery, I have set those classes equal to an array value, like so:

```
var spacesArray = [
    "a1", "a2", "a3",
    "b1", "b2", "b3",
    "c1", "c2", "c3"
]
```

So spacesArray[0] is equal to the top left space, spacesArray[4] is equal to the middle space, and so on.

I'm trying to create a function that determines when three spaces are aligned in a row or a column. In order to do this, I have included a varriable for the last clicked space, which I have named lastClickedElement.

Ideally, what I would like this function to do is something like this. For this example, pretend that the last space that I clicked on is the middle space (b2).

1. Compare the lastClickedElement (b2) to see if its class matches an array value
2. If it does match, check the elements that are above and below it on the board to see if they have been selected by the same player. In this case, it would be either a2 and c2 or b1 and b3.
3. If three spaces line up either vertically or horizontally, then the game is over and a player has won.

I know this wouldn't account for diagonal victories, but I can deal with that separately.

My question is: How do I access class names and array values together? I'm trying to figure out how to word this, so I'm sorry if this sounds like gibberish.

I want to do something like this (please pardon any wrong syntax):

1. I click on the space b2, making it the lastClickedElement.
2. I want to check its class (.b2) against its position in the array (spacesArray[4]).
3. After confirming that .b2 is the same as spacesArray[4], I want to check the spaces above and below it, so I guess it would check something like spacesArray[4+3] and spacesArray[4-3].
4. Then it would check the spaces to the side of it, spacesArray[4+1] and spacesArray[4-1].
5. Once a space has been clicked on, it either adds the class "spaceTakenPlayer1" or "spaceTakenPlayer2" depending on whose turn it was, so it would be checking for one of those classes.

Again, I didn't know exactly how to phrase this and I'm sorry if it's confusing.

Here is a jsFiddle for those that would like to take a better look:

http://jsfiddle.net/hrd0h8jo/

For the purpose of this jsFiddle, the img on the left is the X and the img on the right is the O. Once the game has been started, player 1's spaces will turn tomato and player 2's spaces will turn cyan.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot in your post, but it seems like the main question is that when an html element with a classname like `b2` is clicked, you need some way to associate that with your `spacesArray`.

So I would include the array index as part of the html elements, using [html data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).  So your html would be something like:

```
<div class="b2 gamespace gamespace-bg unselected" data-index="4"></div>
```

Then in your click handlers you could have something like:

```
var index = $(this).attr('data-index');   // this would equal 4
```

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah, that seems like it would do the trick. Can I still manipulate that number to make it check for other spaces? Like:  

`if ($(this).attr('data-index').hasClass('spaceTakenPlayer1') &&        $(this).attr('data-index' + 3).hasClass('spaceTakenPlayer1') &&   $(this).attr('data-index' - 3).hasClass('spaceTakenPlayer1'))`

Comment: just cast your strings as numbers first otherwise you'll end up with something like 'data-index3':  $(this).attr(+'data-index' + 3).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you create a map of the current game state where every cell contains either a 0 (unoccupied), 1 (player 1), or 2 (player 2):

```
New Game:
[0] [0] [0]  
[0] [0] [0]  
[0] [0] [0]  

Player 1 wins diagonal:
[1] [2] [2]  
[0] [1] [0]  
[0] [0] [1]
```

There are only 8 win combinations. They can easily be listed explicitly. Here is a checkWin function that process a game state map like defined above:

```
function checkWin() {
    var v = 0,
        stateMap = getGameStateMap();


    // diagonal top-left to bottom-right
    v = stateMap[0];
    if (v > 0 && v === stateMap[4] && v === stateMap[8]) {
      $scope.winner = v;
      $scope.gameOver = true;
      return;
    }
    // diagonal top-right to bottom-left
    v = stateMap[2];
    if (v > 0 && v === stateMap[4] && v === stateMap[6]) {
      $scope.winner = v;
      $scope.gameOver = true;
      return;
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

      // Horizontal  
      v = stateMap[(x * 3) + 0];
      if (v > 0 && v === stateMap[(x * 3) + 1] && v === stateMap[(x * 3) + 2]) {
        $scope.winner = v;
        $scope.gameOver = true;
        return;
      }

      // Vertical  
      v = stateMap[x];
      if (v > 0 && v === stateMap[x + (1 * 3)] && v === stateMap[x + (2 * 3)]) {
        $scope.winner = v;
        $scope.gameOver = true;
        return;
      }

    }

  }
```

Here is a plunk to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWubDTTVkpAhgrCCM2Ha?p=preview

It is using angular so it might not help you that much; I didn't want to deal with event binding.